# Why can't I install Gosu into my rbenv Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I installed rbenv yesterday to install Gosu.
I followed "[How to Install Rbenv on OS X](http://ejholmes.github.io/2012/01/24/how-to-setup-rbenv.html)" and everything worked fine.

Today, I started a new Gosu project, and it gave me this error:

```
 my_game.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- gosu (LoadError)
from my_game.rb:1
```

So I tried:

```
gem install Gosu
```

Which gives:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

But rbenv global gives:

```
1.9.3-p0
```

What is going on? Shouldn't the running Ruby be 1.9.3-p0? I tried `rbenv rehash` several times and I also tried `rbenv init`.

I also have:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

in my ~/.zshrc file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would actually recommend chruby.  But you can debug this more.  What is the rbenv command for switching rubies and did you run it?  What does it say if you type `which gem`?

Comment: What is the output of `gem env`?

Comment: which gem =    /usr/bin/gem

Comment: gem env = Ruby Version 1.8.7

Comment: OK, so I missed something about the Gem. What did I miss? And thanks for your responses.

Comment: Also, ruby -v gives: 1.9.3-p0